# Blogger layout images not aligning to left

Tags: html, css, post, layout, blogger

I have problem to fix the post main pictures, they are not aligning to the left side and drives me nuts! It is possible to do it post by post manually, but there should be way to do so for all posts.
As well the header image apereantly is not responsive, so it is not stretching for larger screens. 
Don't know what is causing the problem.

The [site](http://hladova.blogspot.cz) is this one.

Could someone help me? 
Thank you so much!
Best, 
Ieva

Comment: Please review [ask] and [mcve] - better questions make for better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your CSS code

```
.post-body img {
    float: left;
}
```